# Moving table view cells from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to stack overflow and a student currently learning `objective-C` at university. I am building an APP for the science museum in London and I'm creating an events planner.

I have two table views set up in two different View Controllers.

The first View controller and table view is called "Events" and it holds all of the current days events. When you click on an event, it goes into a new View Controller, gives more information about the event and has a button to "Add To Events", which pops up an alert saying: "Are you sure you want to add this to your events?" with an add button and dismiss button accordingly.

The information in this table view is populated using three `NSMutableArray`'s. (One for title, subtitle and image).

The second view controller has an empty table view inside it. I am trying to make it so whenever a user finds an event they like, they can click into it, see more info and if they want to add it to their own events page, they can. I have got the "Add" button of the alert responding using an `NSLog` message, so the code to implement the adding to events would go there.

My question is, if i click on the first event, and then choose to add it to my events, how do i send the information of that specific tableviewcell that i clicked to display in the second view controllers table view ?

I have looked all over the place for information regarding this and have taken an abundance of Lynda courses online about `IOS` and `objective-C`, but I haven't been able to figure it all out.

Can anybody help?

Comment: if u have any difficulty i can do your project

Comment: Lol thanks but I want to be able to do it myself! Maybe a gentle push in the right direction will do the trick? :)

Comment: good.... keep it up boy

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use three `NSMutableArray`'s to populate your cells. Create one `NSMutableArray` and populate it with `NSDictionary`s with a key for the title, the subtitle and the image. Or even better: create a custom model (subclass of `NSObject`) for your Events and populate the `NSMutableArray` with those.

Now just like your `NSMutableArray` is the data source for your first table view controller you need another `NSMutableArray` as the data source for the second table view controller. When a user now clicks on "Add To Events" all you have to do is add the Event (Model or Dictionary) to the `NSMutableArray` of the second table view controller and either call `- (void)reloadData` on your table view so that it reloads ALL data or use the "Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections" methods from the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This would be the better approach because it does not reload data that does not need to be reloaded.

Comment: How do you init a dictionary to hold a title, subtitle and image? So far I can only seem to make a dictionary hold two items, an object & key leaving the image out.

Comment: NSDictionary *event = @{ @"title" : @"Title of the Event", @"subtitle" : @"Subtitle of the event", @"image" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] };

Comment: Legend!!! I figured it out in the end, I kept the three arrays but made a singleton class declaring the arrays as extern and then used addObject under the alert button to insert them at will! thanks guys!!